# How can I passthough the client-requested host when using NGINX as a loadbalancer?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have an NGINX config:

```
upstream djangobackend {
  server svr1.int.example.com:80;
  server svr2.int.example.com:80;
  server svr3.int.example.com:80;
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://djangobackend;
  }
}
```

My problem is that NGINX seems to be rewriting the HOSTNAME to 'djangobackend' when making requests of the upstream svrX machines.

This is an issue, as I have multiple domain names for the same site (subdomains for larger customers).  So is I request `http://customer42.example.com/index.html` svrX sees `http://djangobackend/index.html` and does not know to customize the page for customer42.

I can work round this with one NGINX virtual server per subdomain (using different upstream names for each virtual server), but this does not scale beyond a half dozen customers.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the docs: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

I just needed to add the line:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```